# phonegap build ios exception with HelloWorld Application

Tags: cordova, xcode5, cordova-3

I am trying to build a helloWorld application using PhoneGap but it seems that is trying to find the .xcodeproj file twice.

phonegap version: 3.3.0-0.18.0

cordova version: 3.3.1-0.1.2

```
$ phonegap build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
   [error] An error occurred while building the ios project.xcodebuild: error: 'HelloWorld.xcodeproj.xcodeproj' does not exist.
xcodebuild: error: 'HelloWorld.xcodeproj.xcodeproj' does not exist.
xcodebuild: error: 'HelloWorld.xcodeproj.xcodeproj' does not exist.
```

It works fine when I build and run from the XCode IDE.

Comment: do you know the specific command you used to create the project? I am wondering if maybe you named your project 'HelloWorld.xcodeproj'

Comment: ```cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"```

Comment: ```phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld``` from the website http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface with the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case it was grep output which was confusing the build script.

Try running the following command just before  `build` or `run`:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=never"
```

---

### Backstory

Source of the problem is in `platforms/ios/cordova/build` script:

My local environment contains:

```
export GREP_COLOR='1;37;40'
export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always"
```

.. which produces nice colored grep output, but it is confusing the above script, exactly at this line:

```
XCODEPROJ=$( ls "$PROJECT_PATH" | grep .xcodeproj  )
PROJECT_NAME=$(basename "$XCODEPROJ" .xcodeproj)
```

A permanent fix would involve changing the line to something like:

```
XCODEPROJ=$( ls "$PROJECT_PATH" | grep --color=never .xcodeproj  )
PROJECT_NAME=$(basename "$XCODEPROJ" .xcodeproj)
```

Cheers!

Comment: going to test this approach soon.

Comment: Wondering why they haven't fixed this issue. is really nasty.

Comment: Huge thanks on diving into this, had this come up getting someone started with Cordova and there's no way I would have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the folder being created for iOS platform (hello/platforms/ios) and run the command again.

Comment: I removed the ios folder but it doesn't seem to help at all. It seems that the ```phonegap``` cli tool is appending an extra .xcodeproj extension. This is not happening for android project at all