# Error "Command failed with exit code 66" running ios simulator on meteor app

Tags: ios, xcode, meteor

I am trying to run a simulation for ios of my meteor app, following all the steps:

```
meteor install-sdk ios

meteor add-platform ios
meteor run ios
```

But when I run the latter it gives me the following error:

```
Error while running for mobile platforms: Error running
/Users/ivanmac/.meteor/packages/meteor-
tool/.1.0.41.azxhr5++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-
os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh
xcodebuild: error: 'test_app.xcodeproj.xcodeproj' does not exist.
Error: /Users/ivanmac/Desktop/test_app/.meteor/local/cordova-
build/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit
code 66
at ChildProcess.whenDone
(/Users/ivanmac/.meteor/packages/meteor-
tool/.1.0.41.azxhr5++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-
os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-
lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)


Running command: /Users/ivanmac/Desktop/test_app/.meteor/local/cordova-
build/platforms/ios/cordova/build 
Build settings from command line:
ARCHS = i386
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = 
/Users/ivanmac/Desktop/test_app/.meteor/local/cordova-
build/platforms/ios/build/emulator
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.1
VALID_ARCHS = i386
```

Only post I found on the internet talking about this was solved by changing the path, which I tried but didn't help. I'm using Meteor 1.0.3.2 and my xcode is on version 6. Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening?

**Update to question**

I just found out that if I run the .xcodeproj file on the cordova/ios folder manually the project runs fine, so I guess the path to look for the file to run on xcode when I run "meteor run ios" has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open platforms/ios/cordova/build and change

XCODEPROJ=$( ls "$PROJECT_PATH" | grep .xcodeproj  )
PROJECT_NAME=$(basename "$XCODEPROJ" .xcodeproj)

to

XCODEPROJ=$( ls "$PROJECT_PATH" | grep --color=never .xcodeproj  )
PROJECT_NAME=$(basename "$XCODEPROJ" .xcodeproj)

Source: [phonegap build ios exception with HelloWorld Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915395/phonegap-build-ios-exception-with-helloworld-application)